# Microsoft Word on Mac OS: Customise theme fonts and colours

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, fonts, colors, themes

The "customise theme colours" and "customise fonts" dialogue boxes are not available in Word for Mac OS (this is present in the Windows versions since Office 2010 as far as I remember).

[Screenshot of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63ASJ.png)

I can therefore only use the prebuilt colour schemes and font sets. Is there any **easy** workaround on this? I know this is all about changing the +Body and +Heading styles (and Normal/Accent 1/Accent 2 colour stuffs) but I cannot figure out where to change them on Mac .

I'm using Office 365, which means I should be using the latest versions available.

Answer (score 2):

I worked around this issue, at least in part, by putting the following contents in a the file `/Users/$USERNAME/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Themes/Theme Fonts/Example.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<a:fontScheme name="Arial" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
  <a:majorFont>
    <a:latin typeface="Arial"/>
    <a:ea typeface="" />
    <a:cs typeface="" />
  </a:majorFont>
  <a:minorFont>
    <a:latin typeface="Arial"/>
    <a:ea typeface="" />
    <a:cs typeface="" />
  </a:minorFont>
</a:fontScheme>
```

If you back to the Fonts menu in Word, the new set of fonts will appear under 'Custom'.  Right-clicking this and clicking 'Edit' will do nothing, which seems to be a bug.

A list of tags for this file is at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.drawing?view=openxml-2.8.1.  The good news is it appears you don't need to restart Word to pick up any changes in the file.

Comment: Your method works for creating custom theme colour palettes as well, they are stored as XML files in `~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Themes/Theme Colors`. As an example, here is my [Monochrome.xml](https://gist.github.com/Khazbs/d63f17d6820f0596074ab6560daee424) palette file, black and white only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you **cannot create** custom Office **font sets** on macOS using the UI.

However, you **can create** custom Office **colour palettes** in PowerPoint:

- Open a PowerPoint presentation,
- Go to *Design* tab,
- Hover over colour variants and click the dropdown arrow,
- Click *Colours* > *Customize colours*,
- Set up the colour palette and click *Save*.

Now you can **use** your custom **colour palettes**, for example in Word:

- Open a Word document,
- Go to *Design* tab,
- Click *Colours*,
- Choose your colour palette in the *Custom* section.